# Does malware have to exploit a bug?

Tags: malware, exploit

Lately, I have been trying to dive into the realms of malware and hacking. I have learned that hackers exploit bugs in programs and malware does similarly, but I was wondering whether malware must exploit something or can it run without exploiting anything?

Comment: Sometimes they exploit the user. User receives an email "from the FBI" claiming they are entitled some money from OTAN and they must execute `money-from-IMF.exe` to get the money. And guess what? No money...

Comment: Malware is software that acts maliciously. It doesn't matter how it's introduced or how it manages to cause damage to classify it as malware.

Comment: I see your point

Comment: Frivolous answer: Yes, although sometimes the bug exploited is the one sitting on the chair behind the keyboard.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature! (Anti-feature actually) - Always-listening TV microphone? "That's to improve customer experience!" Secret hard coded admin password in your router? "That's to improve customer support!" Auto-update without consent? "It's not remote arbitrary code execution. That's there so we can protect you from malware!" Contact list secretly uploaded? "That's ! ...Look, computers are really complicated. You wouldn't understand why we need to ..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Malware is any software which performs malicious activities. Malware comes in all shapes and sizes, and with all sorts of infection vectors. Exploiting a software vulnerability is one way malware can spread, but there are many other (often more common) techniques they use, for example:

1. Brute forcing passwords over a network to gain access to a network.
2. Spreading to other computers on the same network over shares, etc.
3. Tricking the user into executing a malicious file with a benign name.
4. Tricking the user into performing an action that executes code (e.g. `ldd`).

Never overestimate the difficulty of tricking the average person into executing malware. Often forgotten techniques such as using unicode reversal on filenames can show a user a different filename than is really present. For example, a file called `history_of_rac‮4pm.msi‬` seems safe enough, right? It's actually `history_of_rac4pm.msi`, but due to unicode reversal, the last seven characters are mirrored, giving the impression that an executable installer is a video! Check the HTML!

It doesn't even have to involve making them run an executable file. There are many actions that execute attacker-controlled code that people do not think about. Consider `ldd` utility in Linux. All it does is list the libraries required by a given executable file. Seems safe enough, as long as you don't execute the file? The reality is that `ldd` is actually a wrapper that executes the file with an environmental variable set which causes the executable, if using a correctly-behaving libc, to output the libraries it requires to stdout and then exit. It is trivial to create an executable which will not do that, so running such a simple "safe" utility on it will actually end up executing malicious code.

Comment: I wish I could upvote It but I now get a clearer understanding of how this works.  Thanks!

Comment: #3 is exploiting a bug, albeit an wetware bug rather than a software one.